# Why error happen when run php artisan on Lumen

Tags: php, lumen, laravel-artisan

I clone a lumen project. Then I create and edit `.env` file and copy from `.env.example`.
I run `composer install` and `vendor` folder was create in the project.
I run `php artisan migrate` and there is error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException: Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes.
```

I find out that most commonly the error cause there are spaces in `.env` file. But when i check, i am sure that there is no space and use quotes `" "`.

I try to run `php artisan` only and same error happen.

Comment: Could you show us the contents of the file? Obv you need to censor sensitive information

Comment: @Mohamed, I try to change comment from /**/ to #  and can run php artisan. My careless.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I check again on `.env` file. I change on comment from `/**/` to `#` and can run `php artisan` command.